# Giving a string a specific length in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Using coldfusion I would like to write a string to a txt document but it needs to be in a specific format

The code I am using at the moment is:

```
<!---SET STRING LENGTH FOR EACH--->
       <cfset initial = "#LJustify(initial, 35)#">
       <cfset lname_final = "#LJustify(lname_final, 35)#">
       <cfset accounttype_final = "#LJustify(accounttype_final, 35)#">
       <cfset amount_final = "#LJustify(amount_final, 35)#">
       <cfset date_final = "#LJustify(date_final, 35)#">

       <!---SET TOTAL STRING--->
       <cfset total_string = "#initial##lname_final##accounttype_final##amount_final##date_final#">

       #accountholder#<br>
       #accountnumber#<br>
       #accounttype#<br>
       #bankname#<br>
       #branch#<br>
       #amount#<br>
       #date#<br>
       #initial#<br>
       #lname_final#<br />
       #accounttype_final#<br>
       #amount_final#<br />
       #date_final#<br>
       123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890<br />
       #total_string#<br>
```

When I run the code however it gives me the total_string as:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
G Sinclair CH 27500 01201212
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
GSinclair             CH                     2750001201212
```

So I need to space the values a certain amount from each other in a neat format within the txt document

So for example in the txt the rows should look like this:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
GSinclair             CH                     2750001201212
DGreen                OTH                    3456001201212
HRamsbottom           SAV                    0581620016181
GSmith                CC                     6326378734827
```

What is the best way to achieve this, should I loop an empty space depending on the length of each variable within the string or is there and easier way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you're mixing the concepts of "plain text" (`total_string`) and "HTML" (the `<br>`) there. And you seem to be viewing your output in a browser, not in a text editor, because all the padding *is* there, just how you wanted it. However one of the behaviours of HTML rendering is that s[equences of whitespace are collapsed by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1). You can prevent this from happening in a browser by wrapping your string in `<pre>` tags.

However if you're wanting the output to be plain text, you should be saving it as a text document and inspecting it with a text editor, not with a browser.

Comment: Great! Thanks Adam! I was using my browser as its easier then having to go to the txt every time. I will remember to use the pre tag in the future as I always output everything in my browser while developing

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CHR for the tab space (`#chr(9)#`) to force a text editor to insert a tab. This won't help the browser (they ignore the tab command in general), but it will format the output for you in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Use

To make Text in the file as you need.

Like,

#accountholder##LF#
 #accountnumber##TAB##TAB##accounttype#